# How do I add the same table to more than one MySQL Workbench EER Diagram?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a moderately complex schema in MySQL Workbench, sufficiently large that more than one diagram is desirable (rather than piling everything on to one large diagram). But when I copy/paste a table from one diagram to another, the table gains a new name, and presumably will be generated as a new table.

Is there any way to include the same table on more than one diagram, without risking inadvertently creating another table?